# [R]: using vector element as a variable in tibble for filter (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame table1 as:

```
library(tidyverse)
table1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 5))
colnames(table1) <- c("a","b","c")
table1[,1] <- c("c1","c2","c3","c1","c1")
table1[,2] <- c(1,1,2,1,4)
table1[,3] <- c(5,6,7,8,9)
```

I can filter properly as:

```
test <- table1 %>% filter(a %in% c("c1")) %>% filter(b == 1)
```

But once I replaced "b==1" with a vector's element as below, it is not working anymore.

```
cname<-c("a","b","c")
test1 <- table1 %>% filter(a %in% c("c1")) %>% filter(cname[2] == 1)
```

Could someone (guru most likely) here tell me how could I use a vector element as a variable here?

Thank you!

Comment: `table1 %>% filter(a %in% c("c1")) %>% filter(.data[[cname[2]]] == 1)`